# Regression lines not properly showing on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I tried plotting regression lines on my data, everything up to that point works fine, but the regression lines get illustrated as "scratch marks" rather than lines.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dZPK.png)

I have tried commenting out seaborn, I have tried using different font sizes and I have changed the "lw=2" value multiple times to no avail. If there are no errors, I should be getting 2 regression lines.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfhKh.png)

Comment: `data['size']` isn't sorted.

Comment: How does one go about sorting ? Please help !

Comment: Did you take a look at the linked thread?